# How to find out who is calling apt-get?

Tags: linux, bash, apt

On my machine someone else is calling apt-get and aptitude many times over again.

How can I add a hook to see who called these? I've been looking everywhere, in crontabs and at many other places but didn't find any clues.

Comment: If you're really stuck, you could temporarily replace `apt-get` with a shell script that records details on it's parent process (`ps -ef | grep $PPID`) before running the real `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check their bash history, but it could be nothing shows up there.

Other option would be to hook into the apt-get command.

1. Make a symlink for apt-get

`cd /usr/bin`

`ln -s apt-get apt-get1`

2. in /etc/profile you can change global bash settings. Catch the apt-get command there and replace it with something that writes to syslog. Add this to the end of the file:

`function apt-get () {`

`USER=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}' )`

`logger  $USER " apt-get "`

`apt-get1 "$@"`

`}`